# Corrupted files after upload using AFKNetworking iOS

Tags: php, ios, apache

Good day Guys,

It's my first time to use AFKNetworking to post a file from my iOS app to our server. I'm getting a random corrupted files from some of my testers. And when I checked the error log I got an AFKNetworking -1001 error "Request timeout". I checked and modified both PHP.ini and httpd.conf to extend the timeout and maxrequestcount to allow my app to have a longer upload process but unfortunately I'm still getting this bug randomly.

Please can someone kindly help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance:)

**EDIT**
Here's the code snippet
     NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

```
[params setObject:@"*****" forKey:@"******"];
 /*
    code that populates params...
 */
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[pdl getApplicationBridgeUploadDirURL] parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
   /*
           code that handles the files
  */
} error:nil];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 500000;

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

//manage queue
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = manager.operationQueue;


NSProgress *progress = nil;

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error*****************************");
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        NSLog(@"Error*****************************");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"***********************************");
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
        NSLog(@"***********************************");
    }
    [progress removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted" context:NULL];
}];

[progress addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:NULL];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: maybe the connection gets lost with mobile network sometimes...but with that less infomations we can only guess

Comment: Oops sorry, I'll post a snippet of my code one sec:). Our testers has a good connection by the way. They can upload images and short videos(less than 2 mins) other than that its corrupted.

Comment: Your net connection is very slow

Comment: That's possible or the connection might be intermittent. Is there a way to use a pause and resume using AFK?